# VsCode not writing .text file in C language to the folder

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

When I am trying to write `.txt` file in VS Code its not working.

I wrote the exact program and still its not working. When I execute the program it doesn't shows any error. I didn't mention any location to the text file still the file is not created ( not writing ).

Can anyone help with a solution for this I use Visual Studio Code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{

    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen("employees.txt", "w");

    fprintf(fp, "this was just created");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where is your executable file located? Probably the file is created there. BTW, you should always check `if (fp == NULL)` immediately after calling `fopen`.

Comment: "3:38:33"??!? What do you mean?

Comment: nope usually the textfile will be created in the default location of program file in vscode but in my case the file wasn't created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to make sure you have the rights to write in the location your code is at. Secondly that the space of your drive/device is large enough to accommodate your file. And last but not least, you have to implement a routine to verify for errors at the moment of writing/reading files.

I modified your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("employees.txt", "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    fprintf(fp, "this was just created");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

And is working fine. So again, check the location of your application. By default the file will be generated in the same location as your executable. Look at the folder in which your code is being compiled. VS has "two" modes: Debug and Release. Look in both folders (if they even exist) and double check for your file.

Usually is \bin\debug*
*It could also be release

Other times will depend on the target/architecture (e.g. x64). So it could also be something like: \x64\Release\